# Why can't I read/sync my Mobi format ebooks on the kindle app for mac?

Tags: mac, ebook, kindle, mobi

I have uploaded several ebooks (Mobi format, not bought via Amazon) onto my Kindle personal library, and I can read them without a hitch on my Kindle device, but not on the Kindle app for Mac. Is this a restriction placed by Amazon or a configuration problem? Is there a workaround? All I want is to synchronyze all of my ebook reading on Kindle, Mac and Ipad.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly cannot synchronize them with Amazon software, because they allow onto their cloud only their products.

You can do it however with a very nice application, [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_osx), which exists for Mac as well as for Linux and Windows.

If you want, you can get around the DRM (Digital Rights management) restrictions by means of a smart app, [which you can download here](http://apprenticealf.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/drm-removal-tools-for-ebooks/). This will allow you to synchronize all your e-books across different reading platforms, by using your Mac as the synchronizing agent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have been using Caliber, and that is not really the issue. The problem is that, while my entire ebook library (Amazon-bought or not) is available on the Kindle device, the CALIBER-CONVERTED EBOOKS (.mobi) are NOT READABLE OR SYNCHRONIZABLE on the KINDLE FOR MAC app. All the ebooks I converted on Caliber and uploaded to the Amazon library are DRM-free, by the way.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for point out what I have missed. Just for the sake of curiosity: can you read all books with Calibre? If so, why do you need the Amazon app for Mac?

Comment: Because I don't want to do all of my ebook reading exclusively on the Mac, but would prefer to synchronize my reading progress on Kindle, Ipad and Mac. It's a really nice Kindle feature that I would like to have for my entire library, if I can: that way I can stop reading on one device and pick up at the same point on a different device later.

Comment: @Joe Though I never use this feature, it does make sense. However, Amazon cloud simply does not allow me to upload, and thus synchronize stuff which I did not directly buy from them, not even pdf files.